# Laravel: Select raw query with filter doesnt return anything

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.8

Previously I was able to display data normally, here it's still not there any filters, this is my code and the result.

Code:

```
$app =  DB::select(DB::raw("
    select
        pel.id as id_pelamar,
        nm_pelamar as nama_pelamar,
        nm_rs as rumah_sakit,
        nm_unit as unit,
        nm_jabatan as jabatan,
        pel.tgl_lahir as tgl_lahir,
        his.status as status,
        pel.tanggal_ins as tanggal
    from (SELECT MAX(id) AS id_tr, id_pelamar FROM t_history_pelamar GROUP BY id_pelamar) x 
        inner join t_history_pelamar his on his.id=x.id_tr
        right join t_pelamar pel on pel.id=his.id_pelamar
        inner join m_rumah_sakit rs on rs.kd_rs=pel.kd_rs
        inner join m_unit u on u.kd_unit=pel.kd_unit 
        inner join m_jabatan j on j.kd_jabatan=pel.kd_jabatan 
    "));
```

Result:
[image: result]

After I add the filter, no data is displayed.

```
$nm_rs = '';
$from = '2020-04-01 00:00:00+07';
$until = '2020-05-01 024:00:00+07';
$name  = '';

$app =  DB::select(DB::raw("
    select
        pel.id as id_pelamar,
        nm_pelamar as nama_pelamar,
        nm_rs as rumah_sakit,
        nm_unit as unit,
        nm_jabatan as jabatan,
        pel.tgl_lahir as tgl_lahir,
        his.status as status,
        pel.tanggal_ins as tanggal
    from (SELECT MAX(id) AS id_tr, id_pelamar FROM t_history_pelamar GROUP BY id_pelamar) x 
        inner join t_history_pelamar his on his.id=x.id_tr
        right join t_pelamar pel on pel.id=his.id_pelamar
        inner join m_rumah_sakit rs on rs.kd_rs=pel.kd_rs
        inner join m_unit u on u.kd_unit=pel.kd_unit 
        inner join m_jabatan j on j.kd_jabatan=pel.kd_jabatan 
    where
        (nm_rs = :nm_rs) AND 
        (pel.tanggal_ins BETWEEN :from AND :until) AND
        (nm_pelamar like :name)
    "), ["nm_rs" => $nm_rs, "from" => $from, "until" => $until, "name" => "%".$name."%"]
    );
return json_encode($app);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have 0 records that meet your where clause. To debug I would pinpoint which `where` statement is causing empty result set by removing them one by one. `nm_rs` and `name` are empty. do you have records that have empty values for those fields ?

Comment: Make sure you have blank string in "nm_rs" and "name" fields because you are initializing it blank and being passed to the query.

Comment: I don't have a record whose value is null, but if there is no request from $ nm_rs or anything else, it means that all data will appear without a filter.

Comment: well, I will check one by one from where, to narrow down the debugging process, thanks

Comment: its solved, i forget to added like (not '=') in every condition, when i needed null value of ewquest..

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

1. I forgot to added like (not '=') in every condition, when i needed null value of request.
2. I convert from timestamp to date, here I used PostgreSql

Here my code:

```
$nm_rs = '';
$from = '2019-11-28';
$until = '2020-04-02';
$name  = '';

$app =  DB::select(DB::raw("
    select
        pel.id as id_pelamar,
        nm_pelamar as nama_pelamar,
        nm_rs as rumah_sakit,
        nm_unit as unit,
        nm_jabatan as jabatan,
        pel.tgl_lahir as tgl_lahir,
        his.status as status,
        pel.tanggal_ins as tanggal
    from (SELECT MAX(id) AS id_tr, id_pelamar FROM t_history_pelamar GROUP BY id_pelamar) x 
        inner join t_history_pelamar his on his.id=x.id_tr
        right join t_pelamar pel on pel.id=his.id_pelamar
        inner join m_rumah_sakit rs on rs.kd_rs=pel.kd_rs
        inner join m_unit u on u.kd_unit=pel.kd_unit 
        inner join m_jabatan j on j.kd_jabatan=pel.kd_jabatan 
    where
        (nm_rs like :nm_rs) AND 
        (pel.tanggal_ins::timestamp::date >= :from AND pel.tanggal_ins::timestamp::date <= :until) AND
        (nm_pelamar like :name)
    "), [
        "nm_rs" => "%".$nm_rs."%", 
        "from" => "%".$from."%", 
        "until" => "%".$until."%", 
        "name" => "%".$name."%"
]);
```